# Using Swipe to bring up a Picker - Xcode 8.3.2

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a photo album in Xcode 8.3.2 (using Swift), each of the Photos has a name (label) and currently I scroll through them sequentially by swiping right.

I'd like to implement a swipe down function that will make a picker appear where I can then scroll down through the photo's names, tap on the selected name and then jump directly to that photo. I'd like the picker to be implemented on top of the existing photo that is being displayed so in effect that photo becomes the background.

How can I do that? Thanks for any suggestion that come my way.

Comment: Based upon your description, I assume you're talking about your own picker and not `UIImagePickerController`. Is that right? Also, is this for iOS or macOS?

Comment: In answer to your question, you'd do custom transition transition like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42213998/1271826. The only difference is that you obviously won't remove the presenting view controller's view from the hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks Rob, Yes, you are correct i'll be using my own picker with just the list of names in it. This one: UIPickerView! It is for IOS. I'll check out your suggested link. Thanks again.