# Fade in a background view during custom animation transition

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewcontroller, transition

I wanted to add a custom transition to my app and followed this amazing answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192127/custom-interactive-transition-animation).

It is working great, but I wanted to take it a step further. I want to have a view on the first page that is alpha 0 or hidden at first but slowly fades in as the user swipes down between the two pages. The top view would have a transparent background so it would appear as though its coming in with the background color. 
A great example of what I mean can be seen in snapchat, when swiping between pages as seen in this screen shot below. 
[image]

The background slowly becomes blue and when the new view comes in its solid blue.

I understand this code has to go in the presentation controller as stated in the original question answer I followed, however I am unsure exactly how I would implement this. Also, when setting shouldRemovePresentersView to false I get a crash here

```
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: 
    UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let inView   = transitionContext.containerView
        let toView   = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to)!
        let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .from)!
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to do something similar to what was done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192127/custom-interactive-transition-animation). So I am going to use the same source to help you understand better.

To add a fade-in/fade-out animation you need to simply tweak the alpha value (opacity) in the `func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning)` method.

```
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    let inView   = transitionContext.containerView
    let toView   = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to)!
    let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .from)!

    var frame = inView.bounds

    switch transitionType {
    case .presenting:
        frame.origin.y = -frame.size.height
        toView.frame = frame

        // set initial alpha value to 0.0
        toView.alpha = 0.0

        inView.addSubview(toView)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), animations: {
            toView.frame = inView.bounds

            // animate to 1.0
            toView.alpha = 1.0

        }, completion: { finished in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
        })
    case .dismissing:
        toView.frame = frame
        inView.insertSubview(toView, belowSubview: fromView)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), animations: {
            frame.origin.y = -frame.size.height
            fromView.frame = frame

            // animate to 0.0
            fromView.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: { finished in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
        })
    }
}
```

To break it down further :

- Presenting the new ViewController: Here the initial value is 0.0 as the ViewController appears to be faded at first and then slowly fades in. Hence use `toView.alpha = 1.0` in the animate block so fade in the ViewController.
- Dismissing the current ViewController: Here the initial value is 1.0 (implicitly so, no need to set it) as the ViewController appears to be opaque at first and then slowly fades out. Hence use `toView.alpha = 0.0` in the animate block so fade in the ViewController.

You can put any other animations in the corresponding animations block, basically right next to `toView.alpha = 1.0` and `fromView.alpha = 0.0`.

As for the crash you get while setting `shouldRemovePresentersView` to false, I think the author of the answer has already provided a solution for it.
You can [check a comparison](https://github.com/robertmryan/SwiftCustomTransitions/compare/master...noremove) to see exactly how to fix the crash.

EDIT: To transition from a button :

```
@IBAction func didTapShowButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
    present(controller, animated: true)
}
```

Don't forget to connect this to the button!

Comment: Do you know how I would be able to run the transition from a button as well, Thanks in advance

Comment: This solution animates the entire presenting view and not just the background of the view. I suggest animating the alpha of the container view which is your inView. This will only animate the background and not the presenting view itself, which is the correct behavior of that snapchat transition.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar in my app where I show an image when a gesture is completed.  I really fade the image out in my application, but I modified it to fade in with just a minor change. In my situation I simply fade in or out an image.  I am using an extension below, but the animateWithDuration examples below might help you.    See code below:

```
    public extension UIImage {
    func showAndFadeOut(atPoint point: CGPoint, sender:UIViewController) {
        let buttonView = UIImageView(image: self)
        buttonView.center = point
        sender.view.addSubview(buttonView)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            buttonView.alpha = 0

        }, completion:  { finished in
            buttonView.removeFromSuperview()
        })
    }

    func showAndFadeIn(atPoint point: CGPoint, sender:UIViewController) {
        let buttonView = UIImageView(image: self)
        buttonView.center = point
        sender.view.addSubview(buttonView)
        buttonView.alpha = 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            buttonView.alpha = 1
        }, completion:  { finished in
            buttonView.removeFromSuperview()
        })
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
image.showAndFadeIn(atPoint: gestureEndPoint, sender: self)
```

Hopefully that's helpful. I remove the button in the completion block but if you want that view to stay on the screen, just remove that line of code.

Comment: how can I incorporate this with that I have in place at the moment