# Present Modally without using auto layout?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, segue

I want to create a segue using the present modally option so that the new view will come in from top to bottom. However this option is not there as "trait variations" is unchecked because I am not using auto layout. Is there another way to do this ?
I am asking so i can replicate the button effect seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192127/custom-interactive-transition-animation) example

[image]

Comment: Trait Variations are for specifying changes to Auto Layout constraints based on the device size the app is running on, it has nothing to do with segues. A few more details are needed for people to help you with this. Are you laying out everything in code or using a storyboard? Do you have an existing segue from the first to second view controller? If so what kind of segue is it?

Comment: Right now there is no segue, the user swipes down like in the example I linked to. In the example you can also tap a button to achieve the same effect as swiping down with the pan gesture recognizer. However to achieve that they use a present modally segue, i do not have that option - how can I achieve the same effect

Comment: Auto Layout has _nothing_ to do with segues or any other manner of transitioning between views. The only mention of the word 'modal' I see in any of the code is in `UIViewController`'s `modalPresentationStyle` property. If you don't have access to that property then you are trying to do this with something that is not a `UIViewController` in which case you need to specify what it is you are _actually_ trying to do. As it stands now  your question has no details about what your setup is or what you have tried so far. In order for us to help you we need all the details.

Comment: @theMikeSwan  In the attached photo "kind" is set to "present modally". I want to do this in my application but the option is not there, after doing some research i have found that you need to have trait variations checked off to have that option available. when checking off trait variations xcode tells me that I must use autolayout as well. I can not use autolayout as my apps layout is being done programatically. I want to be able to switch between view controllers in a visually similar fashion to "present modally" without enabling autolayout

Comment: The question is sheer nonsense. You say: "I want to create a segue using the present modally option so that the new view will come in from top to bottom." Fine, then do that. But you're not going to find it in Interface Builder, or under a rock or a tree. You have to _code_ that transition. You need to write a custom presentation transition animation. Yourself. In code. You.

Comment: Indeed, very hard to see why the answer you referenced, https://stackoverflow.com/a/42213998/341994, is not simply the answer to your question. Do what he explains.

Comment: @matt I already have the transition working with a pan gesture recognizer. The issue is i want the user to be able to switch view controllers by tapping a button the same way as in his example. His example uses a present modally segue to do that. I want to know if there is another way to do it.

Comment: Why use "another way"? The notion "switch view controllers" seems to suggest that this is indeed a modal segue. (Of course you could swap out view controllers in some other way, but then you'd need to have your own parent view controller.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because you turn on Auto Layout does not mean that you can't layout your UI in code.

Turn on the Trait Variations so you can get your Present Modally option in the segue and then don't add any auto layout constraints. It should all work just fine.

In all reality with Auto Layout you can still layout the whole UI in code pretending Auto Layout doesn't exist or you can add constraints in code. I find the best option is to create it all in IB and then use code to override things in specific instances (generally those instances have to do with screens smaller than iPhone 6 sized).

#### Aside:

When you run into this kind of thing in the future create a branch in whatever version control system you are using (you are using one, right??) and see what happens when you turn on the feature that worries you. If it blows up in your face you just roll back to your main branch and try a different route. (Even better if you have your SVN in the could or some other remote location cause then you can delete the whole thing off your machine if needed and pull the working version from the remote)

Answer (score 0):

One mistake I was making was that I was directing the segue to the view controller itself and not the navigation controller it was embedded in. By directing the segue to the navigation controller my custom transition was now being enabled for modal presentation and it is working perfectly.