# What kind view controller transition is that?

Tags: ios, xcode, modal-dialog, transition

Is it custom or native? If it's native, what is the name?

[image: animation]

Comment: Good questions include more than Two sentences ending with question marks and a link. Please, - at the *very* least - describe the transition.

Comment: Joāo, this is a custom transition. You can supplying a custom `transitioningDelegate` for the destination controller like [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42213998/1271826) (though, because your gesture isn't interactive, you can ignore the second half of that answer). Clearly the animation here is different (it's doing an animation of the `transform` of the destination scene), but it illustrates the basic infrastructure of custom transitions.

Answer (score 1):

That is a custom transition. In iOS you have five native transitions and none of them have that animation:

- Default
- Cover vertical
- Flip horizontal
- Cross dissolve
- Partial curl

You can try these by selecting your segue and changing the transition:
[image]

Comment: Why are you answering such a poor question?

Comment: Even though it´s poorly asked, it´s still interesting to know which transitions iOS provide for him since he clearly does not know that. Feel free to vote to close the answer if you feel that it does not fulfill the rules.

Comment: No thanks. Still learning what the rules are. You answered two *very* down-voted questions in one evening and I wondered why. I *do* think your reply to my question in these comments is of more worth than this enitire Q&A - but that's part of *my* learning curve. Thanks for being gracious.

Comment: I have no problem with Rashwan's desire to answer questions like this. Sure, the question wasn't great (OP should either describe or provide animated image of the desired effect; but don’t just have external link that will break in the future), but the OP's intent was clear. It's best, IMHO, to tell or show the author how to improve the question, but go ahead and answer it. The only time I adopt a more petulant tone ("no, I won't answer you until you improve the question") is where the author is either a repeat offender or where the question is unintelligible as it stands.

Comment: Rob and Rashwan thanks you both. @dfd Sorry if the link to the gift and my sentence wasn't enough for you get what was my question. I thought it was enough, but I'll improve next ones. It was just my second question here.