# Cant go back to original ViewController with .left swipe?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a viewcontroller that is embedded in a navigation controller. I wanted a Swipe right to go right left and change viewcontroller from VC1 to VC2, which thanks to people on stackoverflow i managed to do. However now i want to go the traditional way left right (traditional way for push), when swiping left on VC2 that goes back to VC1.

**This is my code in VC1 (to swipe right to go to VC2):**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Swipe right gesture

        let gesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SelectedTopicViewController.performChange))

        gesture.direction = .right
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

}

@objc func performChange() {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goTo", sender: nil)
    }
```

**This is my code in VC2 (for swiping left to go back to VC1):**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
        //swipe left gesture
        let gesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SendMessageTopicViewController.performChange))

        gesture.direction = .left
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @objc func performChange() {
        //self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        //print("swipe detected")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goBackToRight", sender: nil)


    }
```

**Also this is my custom segue code (for both left and right swipe):**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class SegueFromLeft: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        let src: UIViewController = self.source
        let dst: UIViewController = self.destination
        let transition: CATransition = CATransition()
        let timeFunc : CAMediaTimingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        transition.duration = 0.25
        transition.timingFunction = timeFunc
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft
        src.navigationController!.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
        src.navigationController!.pushViewController(dst, animated: false)
    }


}

class SegueFromRight: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        let src = self.source
        let dst = self.destination

        src.view.superview?.insertSubview(dst.view, aboveSubview: src.view)
        dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: src.view.frame.size.width*2, y: 0) //Double the X-Axis
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
        }) { (finished) in
            src.present(dst, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
}
}
```

And this is my storyboard, note that i have one segue going to VC2, and one going back to VC1 (both custom segue using the different classes).

Even if i have a `print("swiped")` when user swipes on VC2 it dosent get printed in console, hence why i think its something wrong with the swipes...

Conclusion: Swipe does work on VC1 and segue to VC2 works, however swipe on VC2 does not work at all...

[image]

Comment: Don’t you want to swipe left to go from VC1 to VC2 and swipe right to go back? The `.left` and `.right` indicates the direction of the swipe, not from where you started the swipe.

Comment: By the way, nowadays, rather than subclassing `UIStoryboardSegue`, we’d generally use transitioning delegates and the like to customize transitions. E.g. if this is for navigation controller custom animations and interaction controllers see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53859210/1271826.

Comment: Finally, make sure the views to which you add gesture recognizers have “user interaction” turned on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Both views have user intercation turned on. I want to swipe right to go from VC1 to VC2, the swipe left on VC1 will go to another viewcontroller. The problem is that the left swipe is not working on VC2, only the built in behavior of  right swiping works in VC2, which then goes back to VC1 which is weird.

Comment: Fair enough. I’d personally still suggest using custom transitions technique outlined in that other answer. Since it was introduced in 2013, it’s been the preferred way of customizing transitions between view controllers.