# Changed segue animation to "Show" but it's stuck in "Modal"

Tags: ios, xcode, modal-dialog, segue, show

[image: This is the Storyboard with NavigationController leading off the span of viewControllers which all have Show segues selected but instead animate modally instead]After creating ViewController informational pages which use UISwipeGesture to swipe left and right between 4 different UIViewControllers, I first selected "Modal" as the segue animation.  But modal animation is contrary to the left/right swipes which should have "Show" segues which better match the user action.  When changing the segue types in Interface Builder to "Show" the animations did not change.  When de-selecting the "Animates" checkbox, XCode WILL eliminate the animation entirely, but then when selecting "Show" it goes right back to a modal segue animation.

Would show a picture of the set-up, but don't know how in StackOverflow

Tried embedding whole stack into a NavigationController and that didn't work.
Tried deleting segue and reforming it as "Show" from the getgo, that didn't work.
Shut down XCode and Simulator and restarted-- that didn't work.

Yet in another part of the same storyboard, "Show" segue works fine.

Comment: If you use a show segue outside of a container view controller (navigation controller or page view controller) then you will get a modal presentation since there is no context to do anything else. It sounds like you want to implement a page view controller or you could use a navigation controller with appropriate unwind segues (you have to use an unwind segue to go left)  and a hidden navigation bar

Comment: All the viewControllers in question are embedded in a NavigationController.  Didn't use a pagecontroller for anything but the visual (dot dot dot); I used UISwipeGestureControls to create the swipe-left swipe-right functionality between the views.  But even the non-swipable views (buttons activate some of the segues) which includes rootController, are animating modally instead of show.

Comment: Add a screenshot of your storyboard.

Comment: screenshot of storyboard added, as requested by @Paulw11

Comment: “Tried embedding whole stack into a NavigationController and that didn't work.” ... it would be interesting to know why that didn’t work because that’s precisely what I’d suggest. I’d use navigation controller and just don’t show the navigation bar and replace all those segues with push segues. (By the way, that provides swipe from left edge to go back for free.)

Comment: By the way, I see segues going backwards. You generally don’t want that, because if you go from A » B » C and then present/show/push to B again, you now have two instances of B in memory and C is still there, too. You generally would would dismiss/pop if you wanted to go back to B (or use an unwind segue). But you almost never want circular references of segues or else you will end up unnecessarily exhausting memory.

Comment: Finally, if you really want to “present”/“show” view controllers, the choice of animation is completely up to you. You don’t need to have it animate from the bottom. You can write your own animation controller to do whatever animation you want. (But I’d still use the navigation controller approach, as that’s even easier.)

Comment: @SagarChauhan - No, I wouldn’t suggest that technique. Apple has provided us the ability to specify the animation controller for the presentation and dismissal of view controllers, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192127/custom-interactive-transition-animation/42213998#42213998, especially if he’s hooking it up to gestures.

Comment: @Rob Sir, That's also very good solution. I'm agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my segues were selected with Show Detail (replace) instead of Show (eg Push).  When in interface builder you'll see you get presented with both of those as the top two selections.  When using a UINavigationController, it expects Show (eg Push) to be selected which will put a Navigation header at the top of your UIViewControllers with a back button.  In the case above, I'll simply write a short amount of code to hide the nav-header at the top of all my informational pages.  I will keep the UIGestureControl left/right swipe code as a novelty item, but there are other ways to allow the user to swipe left and right to new pages (lookup PageViewControllers).

UINavigationControllers and Show (eg Push) animation go hand in hand, and you have to be wary of Apple UX/UI guidelines which protect the sanity of users before you go getting experimental with animations in segues.

Show (eg Push) arranges previous, current, and future ViewControllers like a stack of pancakes, so when you move from one to another you're pushing the top off like the top card of a deck of cards.  Whereas Show Detail (Replace) acts like you're removing the card and replacing it with the next card.  Best way to think of the difference between those two segues.

Not sure why compiler kept the modal segue after I changed it to Show Detail (replace)-- could be a bug with UINavigationControllers?